# Visual studio 2010, how to use code snippets in a method call

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense, code-snippets

I moved from Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2010.

My code snippets work good in Visual Studio 2010 on the start of a line, but not when adding parameters to a methodcall. This did work in Visual Studio 2008.

So when i type this : "`DoSomeMethod([nowiwantmycodennippets!]`", the code snippets are not in the intellisense list.

Does anyone know if this is a setting, or just not working anymore, and if it can be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be bug. If you type your snippet name (i.e. noiwantmycodesnippets) and press ESC to dismiss the completion list (if open), then you can press Tab to insert your code snippet. So it's just a matter of the code snippets missing from the completion list.

You can use the `Control+K, Control+X` key chord to show the code snippets' list also. But this isn't as nice as using it through the completion list.

Comment: Thanks, first ESC en than tab works! It´s not ideal, but its beter than nothing, since I use this a lot. Is there a bugreport somewhere that i can follow, that you know off?

Comment: @Erik - The closest I could find: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/109343/make-code-snippets-callable-from-intellisense

Answer (score 2):

Are you using **ReSharper**? If so, Resharper Intellisense overwrites the VS default one, so that i.e. code snippets do no appear in the completions. Try turning off **ReSharper Intellisense** in the ReSharper Options (*Environment->Intellisense->General*, choose *Visual Studio*).

If ReSharper Intellisense is a must, you'll have to create a ReSharper "Live Template" which opens up for "code snippets" behaviour, only ReSharper is way more advanced -- see for example this one http://www.brianlow.com/index.php/2009/04/06/resharper-live-templates-for-nunit/.

Comment: I'm not using ReSharper, its not working in the default, new installed Visual Studio 2010, with custom code snippets. So its a bug like CodeNaked said. But your hint about ReSharper can be useful for people who do use this.

Comment: @brianlow has apparently forwarded his domain to an about.me page, so whatever content was at that url is no longer reachable. Here's a possible alternative: https://andy.mehalick.com/2012/01/07/fun-with-nunit-and-resharper-templates.

Answer (score 0):

On my machine I just type "public void Test(" and than ctrl+space and type the name of my snippet. Works like a charm. I've got the C# keyboard shortcuts, I think.

Comment: This works indeed, but its not the method itself, but the methodcall. So when you call the method: Test(nowmysnippet), that does not work.